# redirect from one folder into another using nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am running any Nginx file server. I have 2 main folders i.e. folder-a and folder-b. If a user tries to land on /folder-a/abc and it's a 404, I should auto-redirect to another folder like /folder-b/abc. How do I set up such a rule in Nginx? My top folder names will always be hard-coded names like folder-a and folder-b.

Comment: If you want to look for a file in one of two locations, use `try_files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As being said by @RichardSmith, if you want to look for a file in one of two locations, you can use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive:

```
location ~ ^/folder-a(?<suffix>/.*) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /folder-b$suffix /folder-b$suffix/ =404;
}
```

If you want to generate an HTTP redirect, you can use [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive with the additional named location:

```
location ~ ^/folder-a(?<suffix>/.*) {
    error_page 404 @redirect;
}

location @redirect {
    return 301 /folder-b$suffix;
}
```

If you have some additional configuration directives in your root location (`location / { ... }`), you should either duplicate them inside the `location ~ ^/folder-a(?<suffix>/.*) { ... }` or move them to the `server` context if there are no other locations where those directives should not be applied.

Comment: I did use the redirect code as above, but looks like all clicks on folder-a is taking to folder-b

Comment: `code`
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        server_name localhost;
        listen 80;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            autoindex on;               
            autoindex_exact_size off;   
            autoindex_localtime on;     
        }

        location ~ ^/folder-a(?<suffix>/.*) {
           error_page 404 @redirect;
        }

        location @redirect {
            return 301 /folder-b$suffix;
        }
        
    }
}
`code`

Comment: Both my folders are inside /usr/share/nginx/html/

Comment: With your configuration directives `root`, `include mime.types` and all the `autoindex` ones are applied only to the `location / { ... }` and not the other one. Move them to the `server` context (and `include mime.types` is usually placed at the `http` context). Remove trailing slash from `root /usr/share/nginx/html/` directive. You can omit `location / { }` at all.

Comment: `code`
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        server_name localhost;
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        
        autoindex on;               
        autoindex_exact_size off;   
        autoindex_localtime on;
        
         location ~ ^/folder-a/(.+)$ {
           error_page 404 @redirect;
        }

        location @redirect {
            return 301 /folder-b/$1;
        }
    }
}
`code`

Comment: Changed code to look like above, as per your suggestion. Any changes required. Was able to get it to work as needed.

Comment: Your new config looks ok. You slightly changed regex part, but in practice it won't make any difference, both variants works equally. I have added a note about additional configuration directives to my answer.

Comment: I removed the root location only, so it should be fine.

Comment: On similar lines I have another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67721091/merge-directory-listing-for-2-different-folders-nginx any help would be much obliged.

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible. Well, you can write your own backend with PHP to generate such a joined index file or even write your own advanced version of [`ngx_http_autoindex_module`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_autoindex_module.c) and add such a feature :))

Comment: If my folders folder-a and folder-b are on 2 different NFS mounts. Maybe something of unionfs would work? and then new folder can be linked for ngingx file explorer?

Comment: Maybe something like unionfs/overlayfs/aufs could work, but I never used them and this is outside the scope of the original question.